# Evaluating inequalities in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and would like to evaluate the following statement:

```
DT17 >= DT13 >= DT37 > 0
```

where these are 2D arrays. I'm a bit confused by the which statement. Is there a way to get the results that are 2D with 0 where false and 1 where true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `&`. For example:

```
set.seed(123)
m1 <- matrix(sample(-3:3, 9, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3)
m2 <- matrix(sample(-3:3, 9, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3)
m3 <- matrix(sample(-3:3, 9, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3)

m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1    3    0
[2,]    2    3    3
[3,]   -1   -3    0
m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    3
[2,]    3    1   -2
[3,]    0   -3   -3
m3
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1    1    1
[2,]    3    1    1
[3,]    3    3    0
res <- m1>m2 & m2 < m3 & m3 >= 0
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And in order to convert this to numbers:

```
res[] <- as.numeric(res)
res
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    1
```